# Are there any recordings of Emil Krebs?

Tags: multilingualism

The German polyglot Emil Krebs [allegedly mastered 68 languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Krebs). Which, frankly, I find unbelievable. I cannot find any reliable source that is well documented, but perhaps recordings of Emil Krebs would persuade me.

According to the Wikipedia article, Krebs died in 1930, so it should have been possible to record him, speaking all those different languages. So, my simple question is:

**Are there any recordings of Emil Krebs, speaking languages other than German?**

For clarity:

- I am *not* asking whether learning that many languages is possible or not - no need to explain your opinion on that.
- The actual number of languages he learned is also unimportant, I am only interested in recordings.

<sup>(I am not familiar with the tag system of this site, and also could not create the tags I need, because of the low rep. [recording](/questions/tagged/recording) and [polyglot](/questions/tagged/polyglot) would have been nice. Please retag the question if needed and remove this line.)</sup>

Comment: It would be good to ask on [Skeptics.se] where there's really evidence that he "mastered" all those languages.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am asking for recordings of Emil Krebs - regardless of whether that counts as "evidence" or not. But feel free to suggest the question be migrated to Skeptics, if you still feel that's necessary.

Comment: No, I was suggesting an additional question. This one should stay here.

Comment: @curiousdannii I see, thanks for the hint! Perhaps I'll try that too.

Comment: Did you post it in skeptics? If so please post the link here. Waiting for an answer.

Comment: @AdelRahimi Yes, but unfortunately, nobody had an answer there either: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/27568/26094.